# template_file can not be open

Tags: templates, tcl

```
# Open user's template file
if [catch { set f_id [open "$ex_doc_template_file" r] } res] {
    # Close output file before abort
    global html_output_file_id

    catch { close $html_output_file_id }

    MOM_abort "$ex_doc_template_file can not be open!"
}
```

I have the above code which need to open a template file, few days ago still working, yesterday just start showing can not be open, could help what is the problem on it?

Comment: Any change gone into that template file? Like file permission etc? I think problem might lie there.

Answer (score 0):

The error message will be in the `res` variable. That should tell you what is wrong; add it to the abort message, perhaps like this:

```
MOM_abort "$ex_doc_template_file can not be open! $res"
```

Then you'll find that it is probably something obvious.

---

In general, when handling failures by reporting something, it's *very* useful to report the actual failure message as that often says what the problem is. I find that Tcl's messages are useful, at least for the immediate error. (The higher-level reasons why can take thought, of course.)